# Beautifulsoup loop troubles

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have two loops Id like to integrate into my script but not sure how as I am still learning all this.

Loop 1) An outside list of book authors; remove this from the code. The list will get longer over time so moving it to an outside file would be helpful. How can I reference a list and add a variable in the code to run through each author in the search?

Loop 2) Im having to repeat my code for each author at this stage. How can I write it once and have it repeat once the search is done for the next author.

*The end goal here is to export the search in HTML format so it easily read through.

Thanks!

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import time

#Loop 1
var1 = 'Stephen%20King'
var2 = 'J.%20K.%20Rowling'
var3 = 'James%20Patterson'
var4 = 'John%20Grisham'

timestr = time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")

#Loop 2
file = open('/var/script/exp/exp_' + timestr + '.html', 'a+')

with open('/var/script/exp/exp_' + timestr + '.html', 'a') as file_1, open('/var/script/src/header.html', 'r') as file_2:
    for line in file_2:
         file_1.write(line)

with open('/var/script/exp/exp_' + timestr + '.html', 'a') as file_1, open('/var/script/src/subheader.html', 'r') as file_2:
    for line in file_2:
         file_1.write(line)

for i in range(5):
    url = 'https://www.example.com/Listings?st=' + var1 + '&sg=&c=&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&p={}'.format(i)
    source = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

    for products in soup.find_all('li', class_='widget'):
        image = products.find('img', class_='lazy-load')
        itemurl = products.find('a', class_='product')
        title = products.find('div', class_='title').text
        countdown = products.find(class_='product-countdown')
        price = products.find(class_='product-price').find(class_="price").text
        file = open('/var/script/exp/exp_' + timestr + '.html', 'a+')
        file.write('<div class="col-md-15 col-xs-3">')
        file.write('<div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">')
        file.write('<img class="card-img-top" src="')
        file.write(image.get('data-src'))
        file.write('" alt="Card image cap" height="200px">')
        file.write('<div class="card-body">')
        file.write('<div><p class="card-text"><a href="https://www.example.com' + itemurl.get('href')+'" target="_blank">' +  title + '</a>' + price +  '</p>')
        file.write('<div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">')
        file.write('<div class="btn-group">')
        file.write('<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary"><a href="https://www.example.com' + itemurl.get('href')+'" target="_blank">View</a></button>')
        file.write('</div><small class="text-muted">')
        file.write(countdown.get('data-countdown'))
        file.write('</small></div></div></div></div></div>')
        print

    file.close()

print(var1)

#Repeated Code
file = open('/var/script/exp/exp_' + timestr + '.html', 'a+')

with open('/var/script/exp/exp_' + timestr + '.html', 'a') as file_1, open('/var/script/src/subheader.html', 'r') as file_2:
    for line in file_2:
         file_1.write(line)


for i in range(5):

    url = 'https://www.example.com/Listings?st=' + var2 + '&sg=&c=&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&p={}'.format(i)
    source = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

    for products in soup.find_all('li', class_='widget'):
        image = products.find('img', class_='lazy-load')
        itemurl = products.find('a', class_='product')
        title = products.find('div', class_='title').text
        countdown = products.find(class_='product-countdown')
        price = products.find(class_='product-price').find(class_="price").text
        #print(image.get('data-src'))
        #file.write('<img src="', + image.get('data-src'), + '">')
        file = open('/var/script/exp/exp_' + timestr + '.html', 'a+')
        file.write('<div class="col-md-15 col-xs-3">')
        file.write('<div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">')
        file.write('<img class="card-img-top" src="')
        file.write(image.get('data-src'))
        file.write('" alt="Card image cap" height="200px">')
        file.write('<div class="card-body">')
        file.write('<div><p class="card-text"><a href="https://www.example.com' + itemurl.get('href')+'" target="_blank">' +  title + '</a>' + price +  '</p>')
        file.write('<div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">')
        file.write('<div class="btn-group">')
        file.write('<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary"><a href="https://www.example.com' + itemurl.get('href')+'" target="_blank">View</a></button>')
        file.write('</div><small class="text-muted">')
        file.write(countdown.get('data-countdown'))
        file.write('</small></div></div></div></div></div>')
        print

    file.close()

print(var2)
```

**Thanks so much for the response DoubleDouble**
So here is the updated code where I was able to use a author list, man im surprised it got this!! LOL

```html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import time

for i in range(5): #searches through pages
lines = open('C:\\Users\\ataylor_dev\\Documents\\VSCODE\\Python\\BeautifulSoup\\Training\\authors.txt').read().splitlines()
for author in lines:   
    url = 'https://www.example.com/Listings?st=' + author + '&sg=&p={}'.format(i) #adds authors and pages to 
    print(url)

#how to repeat code with next author


Output:

https://www.example.com/Listings?st=Stephen%20King&sg=&c=&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&p=0
https://www.example.com/Listings?st=J.%20K.%20Rowling&sg=&c=&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&p=0
https://www.example.com/Listings?st=James%20Patterson&sg=&c=&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&p=0
https://www.example.com/Listings?st=John%20Grisham&sg=&c=&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&p=0
John%20Grisham
https://www.example.com/Listings?st=Stephen%20King&sg=&c=&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&p=1
https://www.example.com/Listings?st=J.%20K.%20Rowling&sg=&c=&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&p=1
https://www.example.com/Listings?st=James%20Patterson&sg=&c=&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&p=1
https://www.example.com/Listings?st=John%20Grisham&sg=&c=&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&p=1
John%20Grisham
https://www.example.com/Listings?st=Stephen%20King&sg=&c=&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&p=2
https://www.example.com/Listings?st=J.%20K.%20Rowling&sg=&c=&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&p=2
https://www.example.com/Listings?st=James%20Patterson&sg=&c=&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&p=2
https://www.example.com/Listings?st=John%20Grisham&sg=&c=&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&p=2
John%20Grisham
https://www.example.com/Listings?st=Stephen%20King&sg=&c=&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&p=3
https://www.example.com/Listings?st=J.%20K.%20Rowling&sg=&c=&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&p=3
https://www.example.com/Listings?st=James%20Patterson&sg=&c=&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&p=3
https://www.example.com/Listings?st=John%20Grisham&sg=&c=&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&p=3
John%20Grisham
https://www.example.com/Listings?st=Stephen%20King&sg=&c=&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&p=4
https://www.example.com/Listings?st=J.%20K.%20Rowling&sg=&c=&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&p=4
https://www.example.com/Listings?st=James%20Patterson&sg=&c=&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&p=4
https://www.example.com/Listings?st=John%20Grisham&sg=&c=&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&p=4
John%20Grisham
```

How do I now repeat the code in the right order? Stephen%20King pages 1 - 5, then on to the next author.. pages 1 - 5.

I feel like im getting pretty darn close, Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, in loop 1 you would like to read in the Authors name from some outside file. Please see below question (and snippet)

[In Python, how do I read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/in-python-how-do-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

```
with open('filename') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

Then, rather than copy-pasting code for every variable, you'd like to *loop* through the list you read in.

[This Link](http://www.diveintopython.net/file_handling/for_loops.html) explains much better and thoroughly than I can but here is a small snippet from there.

```
>>> li = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> for i in range(len(li)):
...     print li[i]
```

To help make the connection of how this is useful to you, compare the following:

```
var1 = 'Stephen%20King'
var2 = 'J.%20K.%20Rowling'
var3 = 'James%20Patterson'
var4 = 'John%20Grisham'

print(var1, var2, var3, var4)

#VS

vars = []

vars.append('Stephen%20King')
vars.append('J.%20K.%20Rowling')
vars.append('James%20Patterson')
vars.append('John%20Grisham')

print(vars)
print(vars[0], vars[1], vars[2], vars[3])

for author in vars:
    print(author)
```

Comment: Starting with loop 1; what would be to code Id put in my search string to include the line in the file name? Right now im using var1. `url = 'https://www.example.com/Listings?st=' + var1 + '&sg=&c=&s=&lp=0&hp=999999&p={}'.format(i)` To make sure we have the same goal here; I want the outside file, author.txt to have each author listed to be inserted in the url where var1 is at.

Comment: @cloudjumper2000 Hopefully my edit helps show how to interchange your var1, var2, etc with a list variable; including looping through it.

Comment: Thanks for the update; i managed to get a bit further but still cant seem to get the code to repeat correctly. See above.

Comment: @cloudjumper2000 in your new code, look at where you place the line `for i in range(5)`. Note that the output is looping through each author for each `i` value and you want it reversed. This can be achieved by relocating the `for i in range(5)` within your current code.

Comment: Think I got it. Appreciate the responses!